# discord.py - how to make a command that takes all words after certain symbol

Tags: discord.py

I'd like to make a command like this:

```
async def offer(self, ctx, firstName=None, lastName=None, *, pitch=None):
```

and I want `pitch` to take every character including spaces after the symbol `"`.
An example: The command `!offer Ocean Man Hi, join my team!` works: `pitch = 'Hi, join my team!'`. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to make this command work: `!offer Ocean "Hi, join me!"`. Right now, it just makes `lastName = "Hi,`, and my attempt to solve this is here:

```
if lastName.startswith('"'):
    pitch = str(lastName) + str(pitch)
    lastName = ''
```

but for some reason it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any errors, it just... doesn't work. I can explain in more detail in Discord or some other place I can send you images of the result, but for now, I just want to check if I'm logically in the right place.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do more specificly?

Comment: I can't, it's as explained as I can make it. I want `pitch` to be everything after a `"` symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question well but as I understand, you want all the arguments after `"` must included in `pitch`. So, you can just do:

```
async def offer(self, ctx, *, args):
    pitch = args.split('"')[1]
```

This will assign to the `pitch` all the words after `"`. If there's any problem with this answer just comment because I answered your question as I understand.

Comment: Will this throw an error if there is no `"` in `args`?

Comment: Yes but you can simply fix it by `if '"' in args: pitch = args.split('"')[1]`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help today!

Comment: I'm happy if I did any help